# Design a Python API for existing Java API

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, closures, api-design

I am new to python and I have to design a Python API(version - 2.7) similar to an existing Java API

**Python version - 2.7**

The Java API is as follows

```
public interface Process<T> {

  Future<T> create(Client<T> client)

  //Other methods
}

public interface Client<T> extends Serializable {

  T execute(ClientContext c)

  //Other methods
}

public interface ClientContext {

  File createFile(String path)

  //Other methods
}
```

The equivalent Python API design that I have come up with is

**Approach1**

```
class Process:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def create(self, client):
    pass

class Client:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def execute(self, context):
    pass

class ClientContext:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def createFile(self, path):
    pass
```

**Approach2**

Can I use closures to directly pass the context to the create function of Process class so that I can eliminate the Client class

**Note** The create method of Process class will process async tasks which can be done using concurrent.futures package from python.

I want to know which of the 2 approaches is good

Also open to better approaches as well.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a Python interface like a Java interface? The two languages have very different perspectives and generally an api that works in one language is horrific in another one.

Comment: @sisyphus Thank you for the response. That is the main reason for my post. Could you please suggest some design changes that I can follow for my Python API

Comment: @sisyphus I am pretty sure that Process should be an abstract class In my Python API as it has several implementations. But I'm not sure about the other classes. Would be great if you could provide some inputs

Comment: You need more detail - what is the API for and why are the terms 'Process', 'Client' and 'ClientContext' relevant? To be honest, the use of the word 'Context' in a class name is often a design smell in itself - a class is supposed to encapsulate its context.

Comment: @sisyphus Process is the api exposed outside. Client is like a job which gets created with the ClientContext. Process class processes the job