# Extra backslash gets added when reading a path

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I am new to Python.

I have the following config file

**test.conf**

```
path=Dtest.appender\=console
```

Following is the python code in which I read a config from .conf file using ConfigParser

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

def func(config=SafeConfigParser):
    with open("test.conf") as stream
    stream = StringIO("[env]\n" + stream.read())
    config.readfp(stream)
    for item in config.items('env'):
        print(item)
```

If I print the config value I read it prints as follows with an extra backslash.

```
('path', 'Dtest.appender\\=console')
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "it *prints* as follows": because that is the representation of an (escaped) backslash in a string.

Comment: Try printing the single element inside the tuple instead.

Comment: @Evert I tried printing it in a tuple. It just prints the same. I want to know if the config values have changed or if python prints raw strings like that

Comment: The value has not changed, Evert is correct. The way to represent a backslash in Python is with two backslashes due to escaping.

Comment: @Evert  Can you take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843165/design-a-python-api-for-existing-java-api?noredirect=1#comment63153623_37843165

Comment: Your link points to a comment on a question (asked by you) about "Design a Python API for existing Java API". Sure I'll take a look, but it absolutely makes no sense to me with regards to this question (other than being from the same author).

Comment: @Evert It's not related to this question. But your inputs on that could be helpful. Thank you